# How can two people make changes to Power Query and Power BI dataset?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

If you happen to know the answer to this question, I would appreciate it: How can two people be allowed to edit the dataset and the PowerQuery editor of a PowerBI desktop file?

Here is some context on my situation:

- My manager is the owner of the Power BI desktop file. She created a shared workspace on the PowerBI service (web version) and uploaded this PowerBi report.
- I can only create visuals on the PowerBI service (web version) with the dataset that she sets up using Power query and other manual modifications.
- She is the only person who can edit the power query and dataset.
- I am trying to edit the PowerBi dataset and the PowerQuery editor, and then create visuals with the updated dataset on the PowerBI service.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can click the download/export report option in the service, this will save a copy of the report to your PC. You can then edit the report query or data model, then reload it with the changes to the service. However, if your manager makes changes and upload their version, it will overwrite your changes.

You could also have a place for you and you manager to share the file, for example in a OneDrive or SharePoint site, so you can make changes to a primary copy that you can both access, and control changes.